# Vector Calculus intuition: Why is the magnitude of a velocity vector the speed?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

From my understanding of basic Calculus (which could very well be completely flawed), the derivative of position with respect to time would give us the slope at every point of that function, which would be the speed at that point.

In that case, there is no notion of magnitude of vector since the slope is just a measure of inclination of the tangent line at that point.

I don't understand how the magnitude of a velocity vector in a vector-valued function gives us the speed at a point, the equivalent of the slope of a tangent line in a "normal" non-vector-valued function. Why does that make sense?

<strike>Sorry if the functional-analysis tag is wrong, I wasn't sure but it seemed to fit the subject.</strike>

Comment: Let $v$ be the velocity of a particle at time $t$. The displacement of the particle from time $t$ to time $t + \Delta t$ is approximately $v \Delta t$. So the speed of the particle is approximately the magnitude of the displacement divided by the time elapsed, or in other words $\| v \Delta t \| / \Delta t = \| v \|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Velocity is the instantaneous speed with its direction. So the magnitude of its derivative will give you the speed which is actually a scalar quantity. But the direction of the tangent will give you the direction of the velocity.

Comment: Thank you, I know what you said but the part I don't understand is why the vector has magnitude in the first place if that makes sense?
Why not take the slope of the line on which the vector lies, for example?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff slope with respect to what?

Comment: @Ruslan, the xy-plane for example. I understand that slope doesnt make sense in anything other than 2D, but in 2D since the tangent vector supposedly lies on the line tangent to a point x, then the slope of the line should give us velocity at that point and therefore the abs value should give us speed, and that speed should be the same (supposedly) as the magnitude of the tangent vector; however it isn't.

Comment: for ex, with equation $r(t) = <\sqrt{t}, (2-t)>$, the tangent vector at point $t=1$ is $<1/2, -1>$, so the magnitude of that vector (supposedly the speed) is $\sqrt{5/4}$, but the slope of the line on which lies the tangent vector is $-2$, and therefore the speed $2$, which is not the same.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff indeed, you'd be correct. But it's just another description of the same thing. The slope of the tangent vector would be equal to $\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}$ ($k_{x,y}$ are slopes in $x$ and $y$ directions), just as if you'd compute the magnitude of velocity.

Comment: @Ruslan, thank you but how would the slope be equal to what you wrote? Wouldn't you compute the slope of the vector as the y component over the x component? So in the case of the vector $<1/2, -1>$, wouldn't the slope be $-2$ but the magnitude of the vector $\sqrt{5/4}$?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff You should compute slope with respect to $xy$ plane, not inside it. I.e. your slope is in plane containing $\vec r$, origin and projection of $\vec r$ onto $xy$ plane. (remember how you did it in one spatial dimension case) In other words, don't forget the temporal dimension.

Comment: @Ruslan, ahhh ok, yes makes sense. Thank you very much for following up.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff Apologies for just now seeing this. Because that's the definition of vector: a quantity with direction and magnitude. For force, there is direction, but also magnitude, which is "strength". For acceleration, it is the "absolute value for the change in velocity per unit time". It's just the definition we whacky physicists have given it.